# How to convert string in JSON object in android

Tags: android

how to convert string into json in android through api. I am facing a problem is that string cannot be converted to JsonObject. Please clear my problem.

Comment: ..please post ur response..so i can check it out ..whether it is valid json or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily with Gson. You need to add it in your gradle:

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

And for using it, just:

```
YourObject yourObject = gson.fromJson(string, YourObject.class);
```

and now, you are able to use yourObject as a object to use method or retrieve properties.

Comment: Mmmm... where? Try adding more information to your questions so we are able to help you out better. 
For example: Eclipse or Android Studio, String you are trying to parse, errors, etc.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Yes I am trying to Parse. I am watching parsing error is that string cannot converted into Json

Comment: First, try upgrading to Android Studio, which is now the official Android SDK.
If you did upgrade, do as said. If not, you could:
    
    JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("sys");
    country = sys.getString("country");

As said in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Comment: My system not support studio

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google GSON as follows:

`JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(stringToParse).getAsJsonO‌​bject();`

Although I do believe it will be much better if you share the code you used to parse and the response you received.